# Which android layout class do I use to achieve this theme?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm going to have an application which will look like this:

[image]

As you can see, I'll have three buttons (including the envelop icon) aligned in a circle. This is rather easy to achieve in Photoshop, but NOT in android layout XMLs. Which layout class do you think is best in this case?

One more thing, how can I have a completely transparent button with an image in the middle. When I set

```
    android:alpha="0"
```

the image also disappears which is not what I want. Any idea?

Comment: "Completely transparent button" should in fact disappear :) Isnt it? It is completely transparent:)

Comment: As for your question, I think the best layout in this case is `FrameLayout`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is rather easy to achieve in Photoshop, but NOT in android layout XMLs.

Not really - you feel it's easy in Photoshop because you **know** how to do this in Photoshop. Once you have a fair idea of Android layout, that too will become easy for you.

> Which layout class do you think is best in this case?

If I were to do this, I would have used `RelativeLayout` as the position of the two smaller buttons are relative to the larger one. Similarly the buttons as a whole is relative to the screen. So, may be 2 `RelativeLayout`s - 1 nested inside the other.

> how can I have a completely transparent button with an image in the middle

Use transparency as the background.
`android:background="@android:color/transparent"`

Comment: android:background="@android:color/transparent" was the key. "android:alpha" sets alpha for the whole button including its image as well (i.e. the whole view). Thank you ...